# Progressive number in Openrefine column

Tags: openrefine, google-refine

Is it possible to generate a "counter", a progressive number in a column using GREL?

For example, I would like to add `value` to that number to generate an identifier for each record.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each row in an OpenRefine project has an index - a sequential number starting at zero (the first row in the project).

You can access this using 'rowIndex'.

To combine this with a value (I'm assuming the 'value' is a string) to create an row identifier I'd suggest:

From the column containing the value you want to use click the dropdown at the top of the column and choose 'Edit Column'->'Add Column based on this column'
In the dialogue that appears give the new column a name (e.g. Row ID) then enter the following in the 'Expression' box:

```
rowIndex+value
```

Then click 'OK' and you should have your row identifier column